# Java If-else programming logic

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

basically I have made a fix on a bug. The fix has worked but now I am wondering if my logic is flawed. I have pasted my code below.Basically I want to know if the 2 lines marked with `<--` have an issue. I have written that `if data.length >=0` then it equals true, and also `else-if data.length && _routing`, then it equals to true as well. Is my logic flawed ? Will my else-if condition ever be met, or will it cause an issue ? I am having some trouble visualizing it and could use some help. If its flawed, how should I go about it ? Thank you

```
if(data.length > 0) {
  if(data.length >= 0) { //<--
    if (_outStr == null){
      _receivedFileContent = true;
      fileCreate();
    }
    _outStr.write(data);
  } else if (data.length == 0 && _routing) { //<--
    _receivedBytearrayZero = true;
  }
} //added during edit for completeness
```

Comment: Could you properly format your code snippet and add any markers (like the * ) as comments? Makes it easier to read and spot errors.

Comment: I see, how should I change it ?

Comment: I need the else-if condition to be met

Comment: So basically its if data.length >=0,,,,,,,, and also if its ==0 && _routing, which is another condition

Answer (score 3):

One flaw that comes to my mind:

```
if(data.length > 0) {
  if(data.length >= 0) {
   ...
  } else if (data.length == 0 && _routing) {
   ...
  }
}
```

The else-if branch will never be taken since `data.length` is already confirmed to be > 0 when that statement is reached.

Instead you'll probably get rid of the `data.length >= 0` condition as that looks superfluous:

```
if(data.length > 0) {
  ... //e.g. write to stream
} else if (data.length == 0 && _routing) {
  ... //got no data but _routing is true so do whatever is appropriate
}
```

I'd also refactor this part:

```
if (_outStr == null){
  _receivedFileContent = true;
  fileCreate();
}
_outStr.write(data);
```

The problem here is that first you check whether `_outStr` is null and do some initialization in that case. I *assume* that `fileCreate()` will initialize `_outStr` and thus you won't get a NPE in the last line but that's hard to read and requires assumptions or having to look elsewhere which makes the code more fragile.

Without knowing what `fileCreate();` is doing I'd prefer something like `_outStr = fileCreate();`. That way you at least see that the stream is being initialized if it was null before. Probably you might also want to put that entire block into a separate method like `writeToStream(data)` and handle the checks inside:

```
if(data.length >= 0) {
  writeToStream(data); //takes care of initializing the stream if necessary 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was afraid of

Comment: Is there any way I can go around it ?

Comment: could I put _routing first and then data.length == 0 ,,,, Would that work

Comment: @WilliamChang probably, only you know what the program should do. Would that do what the program is supposed to do?

Comment: @WilliamChang you'll probably just want to get rid of the `data.length >= 0` condition. I'll edit my answer accordingly but note that as Peter says it might not do what _you_ want it to do so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: the >=0 condition actually needs to be there, because this condition fixes an existing bug

Comment: I need a way for the >=0,,, and the ==0 && routing to both be there

Comment: can I just change it from else-if to another if statement ? Would that work ? Not my code design, just had to fix a few bugs in it, hoping for not too much changes

Comment: @WilliamChang if you want both blocks to be executed if length is 0 then just do another if-block, i.e. remove the else. But the surrounding if-condition still prevents that case, i.e. you only enter the whole block if length is greater than 0, so that needs to be fixed. - As we also already stated: you'll need to have some understanding of the code and what it is meant to be otherwise a "fix" might introduce other errors. If it's hard to understand or fix without breaking other parts of the code that might hint at a need for refactoring/redesign.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking in terms of *invariants* is a great tool here.

```
if (data.length >= 0) {
     ...block-1...
} else 
// invariant at this point: data.length < 0
if (data.length == 0 && _routing) {
     ...block-2...
}
```

Clearly the `else if` branch cannot be entered.

But this only analyzes the internal if-block; you also have a surrounding if:

```
if (data.length > 0) {
   //invariant at this point: data.length > 0
   if (data.length >= 0) { // implied by the invariant, collapses to true
      ...block-1...
   } else if (data.length == 0 && ...) { // false by invariant, unreachable
      ...block-2...
 }
```

Simplification by eliminating redundant checks and unreachable code gives us this:

```
if (data.length > 0) {
  ...block-1...
}
```

This code will have the same behavior as the code you posted.

Comment: Ah ok I see your logic, basically I should take out the else-if and then have if-else and then another if. So as to make sure that the condition is met. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: So I can just add in the empty else statement there ? Dont need anything since it will take the data.length <0,,, Dont need any extra logic there ??

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data.length>0)   ---------(1)
 {
      if(data.length>=0)      ---------(2)
      {
            ...
      }else (data.length==0)&&(routing))    -----(3)
      {
      }
}
```

The else part of the inner if statement (statement labelled 3)  won't be encountered since the outer if (statement labelled 1) itself ensures that the data.length is always greater than 0. That means, there is no need for an inner else condition that checks for the condition data.length=0. If the else condition was an OR operator; there were chances for that to be executed. But, since its an AND operator and one is always FALSE; this means that , it will never be executed.

Comment: if (data.length >= 0) {
     ...block-1...
} else 
// invariant at this point: data.length < 0
if (data.length == 0 && _routing) {
     ...block-2...
}
    _receivedBytearrayZero = true;
  }
} //added during edit for completeness

Comment: I quite like this answer and wanted to try it out. If >=0 is met ,,,,,,,,,, else

Comment: the a new if condition which if ==0 && _routing

Comment: Could both statements be reached ?

Comment: Since they r two if statements

Comment: No need of that else part because whats inside that else is an unreachable code.

Comment: ah ok, so I will change it from and else if into 2 separate if statements, and since its both if statements, they can both be reached. Am I correct in this assumption ?